# CHKDSK reports drive is RAW when its not

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, chkdsk

How is it possible that chkdsk thinks a drive is raw when its not?

I would like to check this drive but am unable to.

Trying to checkdisk from the gui:
[image]

Here we can see windows thinks `E:` is a healthy drive.

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    446 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3                      NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Seagate Bac  NTFS   Partition   7451 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     J                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 6     L   CNTR_ROAM3   FAT32  Removable     29 GB  Healthy
  Volume 7     P   Videos       NTFS   Partition   3631 GB  Healthy
  Volume 8     E   Downloads    NTFS   Partition   3725 GB  Healthy
  Volume 9     F   Users        NTFS   Partition   1863 GB  Healthy
  Volume 10    Q   Mayfield 15  NTFS   Partition   1863 GB  Healthy
  Volume 11    G                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 12    H                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 13    I   NIKON D7000  exFAT  Removable     59 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk E: /F
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

Comment: I would suggest booting a diagnostic disc, such as [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), which has several disc analyse / repair programs in addition to the standard Windows options; or try a Linux LiveCD, such as [Ubuntu Live](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), which has good support for access and repair to Windows file systems, and its partition editor (`gparted`) is particularly good (there is a `Check` option when you select a partition and right-click on it).

Comment: which windows 10 build do you use? have you installed the latest update rollup?